# multiple css modules with r.js optimizer?

Tags: css, optimization, requirejs

r.js optimiser can create multiple js modules as in

```
 modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            exclude: [
                "infrastructure"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "infrastructure"
        }
    ],
```

Is there a way to create multiple css outputs?
Because one page needs set of css files and another page needs different set of css files.

Answer (score 1):

r.js will automatically inline contents of `@import url(...)` links in all .css files found in the project directory. If you structure your CSS files correctly you can achieve modularisation, for example:

**page1.css**

```css
@import url("common/shared.css");
@import url("page-1-specific.css");
```

**page2.css**

```css
@import url("common/shared.css");
@import url("page-2-specific.css");
```

After running through r.js **page1.css** and **page2.css** will contain actual contents of the referenced files, i.e. contents of "shared.css" will be included in both of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I tell r.js to create page1.css and page2.css separately? I only see cssIn, out option in the r.js documentation.

Comment: @eugene all `r.js` does is inline the contents, you create the files yourself. No special configuration necessary.